# JQuery Validate - reset form using a function, resetForm() won't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using JQuery Validator and I saw many solutions here in stackoverflow, putting all validation in a "var" and then using this "var" .resetForm() to reset the object, but this isn't working, here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markuspxpx/NhWHX/) with my example.

**My intention later:** use same Form, two types of blocks with differents inputs inside and when one of blocks change, I call a method to reset the validation so I can reuse the Validate again when try to submit.

```
 var validate = $('#cad_principal').validate({
      errorLabelContainer: $('.form_validate_message'),
      wrapper:'li',
      rules:{
        cad_pf_cpf:{required:true, minlength:11}
      },
      messages:{
        cad_pf_cpf:{required:"O campo CPF precisa ser preenchido.", minlength:"O campo CPF deve conter no mínimo 11 caracteres."}
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).submit();
      }
  });

function cancelForm(){
    validate.resetForm();
}
```

Comment: You should really check that your example doesn't throw a javascript error before you save it.  Use the console of your browser, the answer is right there.

Answer (score 4):

The function you're trying to call (`cancelForm()`) doesn't exist. Try this:

```
$(function() {  
    var validate = $('#cad_principal').validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $('.form_validate_message'),
        wrapper:'li',
        rules:{
            cad_pf_cpf:{required:true, minlength:11}
        },
        messages:{
            cad_pf_cpf:{required:"O campo CPF precisa ser preenchido.", minlength:"O campo CPF deve conter no mínimo 11 caracteres."}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).submit();
        }
    });

    $('#cad_principal a').click(function() { validate.resetForm(); });
});
```

Basically, you need to wrap the code inside the DOMReady event, and then use event binding to hook up the form. Remember that `validate` will only contain a variable when the DOM is ready. Here's a [**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NhWHX/1/).

Comment: Additionally, you might consider doing a `$('form').get(0).reset();` in your click function to fully clear out the form as well.

Comment: That should be handled by the `resetForm()` method of the `validate` element, anyway.

Comment: Yeah... it isn't though :)

Comment: It requires the "form" plugin for that functionality.  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm

Answer (score 1):

- As already stated, `cancelForm()` does not yet exist.  Wrap everything in a DOM ready event handler function.
- Secondly, you are using jQuery, so the inline JavaScript can simply be replaced with a `click` handler using jQuery's [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- And finally, you do not need `form.submit()` within the `submitHandler`.  It's superfluous, since by leaving out your custom `submitHandler` callback, you'll get a `submit()` [by the plugin's default](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

I also added a `$('form').get(0).reset();` to the `cancel` `click` handler to clear out the form contents.  [As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm), `resetForm()` would require another plugin for this...

> Resets the controlled form. 
> **Resets input fields to their original
>   value (requires form plugin)**, removes classes indicating invalid
>   elements and hides error messages.

---

Try this:

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var validate = $('#cad_principal').validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $('.form_validate_message'),
        wrapper: 'li',
        rules: {
            cad_pf_cpf: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 11
            }
        },
        messages: {
            cad_pf_cpf: {
                required: "O campo CPF precisa ser preenchido.",
                minlength: "O campo CPF deve conter no mínimo 11 caracteres."
            }
        }
    });

    $('#cancel').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validate.resetForm();
        $('form').get(0).reset();
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form_validate_message"></div>
<form id="cad_principal" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cad_pf_cpf" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <br />
    <a id="cancel" href="#">cancel</a>
</form>
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/rnryw/**

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then try this approach (specially for clearing data purpose):

1-   Form html:

```
<input type='reset' class="button_grey resetForm" value='Reset'>
```

2-  Jquery validate

```
// you can add error fields
var validator = $("#cad_principal").validate({
      focusCleanup: true
});
```

3- Reset the form

```
$('[type="reset"]').on('click', function(){ 
      $("#cad_principal").closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); 
      $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked'); 
      validator.resetForm(); 
      return false;
});
```